# Dispatch_async does not execute more than once

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to understand whats happening in my app. When this button is clicked once and connection is established using the singleton class BLEmanager it connects and work accordingly. When the device is not connected, not supported or unknown the UI notifies the user of the issue.

When I try again with the adapter on, it skips the dispatch_async block and does not update the UI. Not sure why it doesn't run the block for the second time, could it be that i am locking the thread.

```
 - (IBAction)connectAdapter:(id)sender {
// connnect to adapter
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("my queue", NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

  [BLEManager sharedInstance];
  NSLog(@"DID RUN BLE MANAGER");
  _adapter = BLEManager.sharedInstance.adapter;
  _transporter = BLEManager.sharedInstance.transporter;

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //update your UI
    if (adapterState == adapterConnected){
         //do stuff like request information and then dismiss an alert controller
     }
  });
 });
}
```

Comment: So, you're not seeing "DID RUN BLE ..." message the second time? If that's the case, I'd suggest putting a log statement before the `dispatch_async` call and I'd wager you're not seeing this `connectAdapter` method get called at all the second time at all.

Comment: Um, try creating the dispatch queue once, outside the IBAction.  I suspect the issue is trying to create the same named queue twice.  Even better, use the [global dispatch queue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452927-dispatch_get_global_queue?language=objc) instead of creating your own.

Comment: @i_am_jorf - The creation of a new queue with the same name would not cause this problem. There's something more fundamental going wrong here. (If you're just saying that it's a little inelegant to create another queue of the same name and less efficient than just using one of the global queues, you're quite right. It just won't cause the behavior the OP is reporting.)

Comment: creating the que with same name refers to the same queue and new queue is not created. Hence not an issue.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq - No offense, but that's not true. Creating a new queue with the same name creates a separate queue that happens to have the same name. It is not the same serial queue (and thus, will not achieve serial behavior between calls, if that was OP's intent).

Comment: Make sure that you are properly maintaining the state in your singleton.

Comment: @Rob yeah. Sorry for that. My mistake.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq I have a big feeling its the singleton im using. What im noticing is that, within the singleton class is where i scan for the service UUIDs. When i try to connect to the device that is not on/plugged in, i come to an error because i think my BLEmanger is not being called.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq Also when the deice is connected and and connect, I send out the characteristics UUID, but in order for the UI to update to say connected on a label i need to click the button for a second time.

Comment: @Rob i think that my adapterState is not being updated correctly. I chose to use the dispatch_async(myQueue) because i read that it would wait for the singleton class to finish executing then processed to update the UI. After connection is established i actually disable selection of the connection button.

Comment: @3rdeye7 - Yep, I'm confident that if you're not seeing "DID RUN BLE..." message, you simply must not be calling this method like you expected. The problem isn't `dispatch_async` or the queue or anything like that, but rather the code that calls `connectAdapter`. That having been said, as i_am_jorf pointed out, while unrelated to your problem, this GCD code is curious because if you want serial behavior, you shouldn't be instantiating queue here, and if you don't need serial behavior, you should just use global queue. But fix your main problem before worrying about these minor GCD issues.

Comment: @Rob what would i use to achieve serial behaviour? Also if a shared instance of a singleton is created would the app wait till the singleton is done initializing or continuing processing in a parallel manner. I chose to use the singleton because i wanted to hold a reference to the BLManager object. Also thank you for the information and help.

Comment: To achieve serial behavior, you want to make sure you instantiate `myQueue` only once (e.g. if this `connectAdapter` is instance method of some view controller, perhaps do it in `viewDidLoad`) rather than every time `connectAdapter` is called.

Comment: @Rob Oh I see, i'm basically firing up new threads every time I connectAdapter. So most likely resources are being locked up or waiting, correct?

Comment: No, I'd be surprised if that was the source of the problem. If you're seeing a ton of the "DID RUN BLE..." messages, then that would be something to worry about, but not if you're seeing it only once. I think you should focus not on `connectAdapter`, but rather whatever triggers in its being called.